# How to save video from an IP camera on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, ip-camera

Is there any ways to record the video broadcast through an IP camera?

Recently, I developed an app that shows the IP camera preview. I used webView for this.
Now, Organizer wants me to record and save videos, but I didn't find any solution. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: show some code, but I highly doubt that this is possible with `WebView`, this should be some native player like `MediaPlayer` or `ExoPlayer`

Comment: @snachmsm Exo and Media player didn't support this kind of video stream but I used VLC player and IpCamView (Project in GitHub) its worked but they had a delay but WebView shows preview without delay.

Comment: well, VLC is also a good choice, but I'm very curious how did you connected native VLC lib with projection in `WebView`. wehn you show your code then maybe someone will help you resolve this

Comment: @snachmsm for Example Ycamera (It exists on google play) do exactly what I want, I want to connect to a Wifi Endoscope.

Comment: ok, post some code and maybe eventually someone will help you